# Angular фильтрация массива

Tags: массивы, angularjs, filter

Есть массив

```
$scope.mass=[{id:1, name:'first'},
       {id:2, name:'second'},{id:3, name:'three'},{id:4, name:'choturu'},
       {id:5, name:'five'},{id:6, name:'six'}];
```

Их него нужно достать и показать элементы у которых id>=2 && id<6. 
Как это можно реализовать через фильтры?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду ангуляровские фильтры?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, в данном случае не важно как массив фильтровать

Comment: @Grundy это ведь совершенно разные сущности.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, которые возвращают отфильтрованный массив

Comment: @Grundy ангуляровский фильтр может вернуть все что угодно, не обязательно массив.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, в данном случае, очевидно, возвращается тоже массив

Comment: @Grundy вполне может быть, что строка например, с запятыми, там же не зря по "показать" написал тк

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, неа, скорее сейчас этот массив выводится с помощью ng-repeat весь, а теперь надо чтобы выводил конкретные элементы

Comment: @Grundy гадание на кофейной гуще, давайте дождемся ответа топикастера.

Comment: Массив находиться в ng-repeat, теперь нужно показать элементы у которых id>=2 && id<6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать `ng-if` для скрытия элементов по условию:

```js
angular.module('fooApp', [])
    .controller('FooController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.mass = [{id:1, name:'first'}, {id:2, name:'second'}, {id:3, name:'three'}, {id:4, name:'fourth'}, {id:5, name:'five'}, {id:6, name:'six'}];
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="fooApp">
  <div ng-controller="FooController">
    <div ng-repeat="v in mass" ng-if="(v.id >= 2) && (v.id < 6)">
      {{v.id}} - {{v.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Можно фильтровать в контроллере:

```js
angular.module('fooApp', [])
    .controller('FooController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.mass = [{id:1, name:'first'}, {id:2, name:'second'}, {id:3, name:'three'}, {id:4, name:'fourth'}, {id:5, name:'five'}, {id:6, name:'six'}];
        $scope.massFiltered = $scope.mass.filter(function (i) {
            return (i.id >= 2) && (i.id < 6);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="fooApp">
  <div ng-controller="FooController">
    <div ng-repeat="v in massFiltered">
      {{v.id}} - {{v.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Можно через ангуляровский фильтр:

```js
angular.module('fooApp', [])
    .filter('yourFilter', function () {
        return function (v) {
            return v.filter(function (i) {
                return (i.id >= 2) && (i.id < 6);
            });
        };
    })
    .controller('FooController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.mass = [{id:1, name:'first'}, {id:2, name:'second'}, {id:3, name:'three'}, {id:4, name:'fourth'}, {id:5, name:'five'}, {id:6, name:'six'}];
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="fooApp">
  <div ng-controller="FooController">
    <div ng-repeat="v in (mass | yourFilter)">
      {{v.id}} - {{v.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Так и получите пожалуйста:

```
$scope.mass=[{id:1, name:'first'},
       {id:2, name:'second'},{id:3, name:'three'},{id:4, name:'choturu'},
       {id:5, name:'five'},{id:6, name:'six'}];

    $scope.massid = $scope.mass.filter(function(entry){
        return entry.id >= 2 && entry.id < 6 ;
    });
```

Comment: как к этому фильтр описать в HTML ?

Comment: @Mikhail121, никак, выводите вместо _mass_ - _massid_ в `ng-repeat`