# Кастомный фильтр в AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, filter

Изучаю AngularJS по туториалу https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05 . Так же там есть живое демо: http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-5/app/

```
Search: <input ng-model="$ctrl.query" />
<li ng-repeat="phone in $ctrl.phones | filter:$ctrl.query">
   <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
   <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
</li>
```

Так вот: как работает этот самый **filter:$ctrl.query**? Очевидно, скрипт циклом пробегает по всему массиву объектов ***phones***, и если есть совпадения со введенным текстом - текущее значение попадает в выдачу после фильтрации. Но фильтр устроен так, что он просматривает все поля, даже те, которые визуально не отображаются. Например, если наш массив phones будет таким:

```
[
    { 
        "name": "Motorola XOOM with Wi-Fi", 
        "snippet": " ... ",
        "sys": "hidden value"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "MOTOROLA XOOM", 
        "snippet": "... ",
        "sys": "hidden value"
    }
]
```

и в `<input ng-model="$ctrl.query" />` ввести `hidden value`, то фильтр тоже сработает. Хотя хотелось бы фильтровать только по полю name. Или же реализовать фильтр регулярным выражением. Допустим, любую букву можно заменить звездочкой. В общем, как реализовать функцию фильтра?

Comment: Вероятно тут есть полезная информация http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/525503/angular-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0/525585

Answer (score 1):

Фильтр под названием `filter` "пропускает" через себя входной массив и возвращает массив с элементами которые соответствуют заданному выражению.
Фильтр имеет вид:
`{{ исходный_массив | filter : выражение_для_поиска : функция_сравнения}}`
в вашем случае используется стандартная функция для сравнения.

Для поиска по заданному полю можно совершить поместив `query` в поле с названием, по которому вы хотите осуществить поиск. То-есть:
`<li ng-repeat="phone in $ctrl.phones | filter:{name: $ctrl.query}">`

Для использования regex понадобится написать собственный компаратор:
В контроллер:

```
this.comparator = function(source, query) {
  return (new RegExp(query)).test(source);
}
```

В шаблоне:
`<li ng-repeat="phone in $ctrl.phones | filter:{name: $ctrl.query}:$ctrl.comparator">`